# Celery - Multiple environments, workers and task set to a worker who doesn't have the task registered

Tags: celery

I have a setup with different environments:
Master (redis-prod URL, and a celery worker connecting to it)
Develop (redis-dev URL, and another celery worker connecting to it)
pc-environment (redis-dev URL)

For clarity, on my pc-environment, I'm doing some testing and use an environment similar to development, it can be me, or anyone else. So my local celery worker also connects to the redis-dev url but also starts a celery worker.

My pc-environment worker and the develop worker have mingled (following celery vocabulary. I checked with flower).

Now, the problem. Locally, I registered a new task, not yet available on the develop environment. When testing it, the task is sometimes done on the pc-environment worker or on the develop worker. When done on the develop one, it complains the task is not yet registered. Which is true as the task is only on my pc at the moment.

Have I done something wrong in my architecture or is there some configuration missing? I tried `--without-mingle` without success.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you can't register task while the worker is running. I am not sure if it does that when you send the SIGHUP signal... - Worth trying. Whenever I have a new task, I re-deploy. That always works.

Comment: How do you handle multiple environments then?

Comment: The code is automatically built, tested, and deployed whenever there is something new merged to master... First to dev, then to staging, and finally to production.

Comment: do you have a different broker instance for each?

Comment: Yes we do have different instances for each environment.